# Forking a part of the php code

Tags: php, multithreading, curl, fork

In my code I am sending a request to another page using `curl_exec`. I do not need the `curl_exec` result for the rest of the script and I do not want it to block until the `curl_exec` request is done and has received a response.

Any ideas if I can fork of a specific part of the script?

Or any other design ideas...?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few ideas:

- Use curl_multi, and close curl at the very end of the request. You could even do this 'after shutdown'
- Use worker scripts, with for example 'gearman'

Or:

- You could open sockets manually, and handle stuff asynchronously using the libevent extension

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the responses of the cURL requests?

First, the pcntl functions you would need to fork are generally a bad idea.

One method would be to place the cURL code in a separate script and exec() that script so it runs in the background.

```
$command = "php ..../wherever/your/kohana/cli/controller/is.php";
exec('php /path/to/curlscript.php > /dev/null &');
```

Outputting to /dev/null & allows the script to continue running in the background.

Alternatively, and probably a better solution, would be to implement a queue system such as Gearman or RabbitMQ.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. My problem is that the script works fine when I execute from command line when not using &. But when adding & it fails. Any ideas?

Comment: The `&` tells the terminal not to wait for a response. As to why it's not working... good question. Do you have access to the terminal so that you can try it outside of PHP?  ALSO, if this is something that's going to be performed often, e.g. because of a public-facing page, you would be much better off implementing a queue system in that case.

Comment: Yep I did it from the console and I got the same problem. I implemented a simple script with "php test.php > log.txt" and it worked fine. The script only did a echo "hello";. When I added & I did not get any log.txt. Strange indeeed.

Comment: What I actually want to do is execute a push to the Google Android C2DM servers and that takes a few seconds. Yes I could do a queue script but I'll go for the fast option to begin with...

Comment: If you can't find out why the & symbol (run process in background) doesn't work, after some Googling, it may be worth asking a question on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ about it. I'm not aware of any reasons why it wouldn't work. Sorry I can't be of help there.

Comment: Got it to work from Apache/Php but not command line :-) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [curl-multi-exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php), might be what you need:

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't support forks and threads, but you can get rid of the response by setting a response timeout:

```
function curl_post_async($url, $params)
{
  foreach ($params as $key => &$val) {
    if (is_array($val)) $val = implode(',', $val);
      $post_params[] = $key.'='.urlencode($val);
  }
  $post_string = implode('&', $post_params);

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'curl');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
}
```

Taken from: [How to post an asynchronous HTTP request in PHP](http://petewarden.typepad.com/searchbrowser/2008/06/how-to-post-an.html)

As the [CURL documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), you can use `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` since PHP 5.2.3 and CURL 7.16.2.

Comment: This will still block for at least a second